# ASP.NET MVC HTML helper methods for new HTML5 input types

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, html, html-helper, html-input

HTML5 appears to support a new range of [input fields](http://diveintohtml5.info/forms.html) for [things such as](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/states-of-the-type-attribute.html#states-of-the-type-attribute):

- Numbers
- Email addresses
- Colors
- URLs
- Numeric range (via a slider)
- Dates
- Search boxes

Has anyone implemented `HtmlHelper` extension methods for ASP.NET MVC that generates these yet?  It's possible to do this using an overload that accepts `htmlAttributes`, such as:

```
Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Foo, new { type="number", min="0", max="100" })
```

But that's not as nice (or typesafe) as:

```
Html.NumericInputFor(model => model.Foo, min:0, max:100)
```

Comment: What's the meaning of "typesafe" for the examples you share here? I can see the difference in both codes, but I don't get why one is typesafe and the other one is not.

Comment: @carloswm85 the first snippet uses an anonymous type. It's not typesafe because the compiler doesn't check the names of any of the properties. You could mistype `min` as `man` and your code would compile correctly but not produce the desired result, because of a typing error. If it were typesafe, this error would be caught.

Comment: So that happens in the first snippet because it is taking an object such as `new { type="number", min="0", max="100" }` as the second parameter? That's why it is not typesafe. Unlike the second snippet, where parameters are orderly set and described in, let's say, "individual parameters".

Comment: Yes, that's right. The compiler doesn't validate anything about `new { ... }`.

Answer (score 54, accepted):

Just a heads up that many of these are now incorporated into MVC4 by using the [`DataType`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.datatype.aspx) attribute.

As of [this work item](https://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/workitem/2) you can use:

```cs
public class MyModel 
{
    // Becomes <input type="number" ... >
    public int ID { get; set; }

    // Becomes <input type="url" ... >
    [DataType(DataType.Url)]
    public string WebSite { get; set; }

    // Becomes <input type="email" ... >
    [DataType(DataType.EmailAddress)]
    public string Email { get; set; }

    // Becomes <input type="tel" ... >
    [DataType(DataType.PhoneNumber)]
    public string PhoneNumber { get; set; }

    // Becomes <input type="datetime" ... >
    [DataType(DataType.DateTime)]
    public DateTime DateTime { get; set; }

    // Becomes <input type="date" ... >
    [DataType(DataType.Date)]
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }

    // Becomes <input type="time" ... >
    [DataType(DataType.Time)]
    public DateTime Time { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: @Drew - believe date, datetime and time are included in that work item (they are certainly part of mvc4 release). why do you say otherwise?

Comment: I misinterpreted the comment: _We need to do this automatically for tel, url, email, datetime, date, time, and number._ I've linked to the docs and extended the sample code. Nice find, thanks.

Answer (score 23):

Check out the  [ASP.net MVC HTML5 Helpers Toolkit](http://mvchtml5.codeplex.com/)

Comment: doesn't MVC support HTML5 by deafault?

Answer (score 15):

Easiest way is to simply add type="Email" as an html attribute. It overrides the default type="text". Here is an example with a html5 required validator also:

```
@Html.TextBox("txtEmail", "", 
    new { placeholder = "email address", 
          @type="email", 
          @required = ""
    })
```

Comment: That's pretty much what I show in the original question. I was looking for a more typesafe solution.

Comment: Hi @Drew - your are completely right, by the time i read the answers I had forgotten your original question - sorry!

Comment: No worries. Your code definitely works, but I would like to avoid using anonymous types, both for performance and because they're not checked by the compiler for correctness.

Comment: This answer definitely worth being here. Googled this question up - found this solution

Comment: This is the answer I found most easy to implement. I didn't want to have to use `Editor` helper, and this answer supports that inclination.

Answer (score 11):

What i don't like about *DataTypes* Attributes is that u have to use *EditorFor* in the view. Then, you can't use **htmlAttributes** to decorate your tag. There are other solutions but i prefer this way.

In this example i only extended the signature i use the most.

So in the class:

```
using System.Linq.Expressions;
namespace System.Web.Mvc.Html
{
    public static class HtmlExtensions
    {
        public static MvcHtmlString EmailFor<TModel, TProperty>(this HtmlHelper<TModel> html, Expression<Func<TModel, TProperty>> expression, Object htmlAttributes)
        {
            MvcHtmlString emailfor = html.TextBoxFor(expression, htmlAttributes);
            return new MvcHtmlString(emailfor.ToHtmlString().Replace("type=\"text\"", "type=\"email\""));
        }
    }
}
```

As you see i just changed the type="text" for type="email" and then i can use in my view:

```
    <div class="form-group">            
        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Email, new { @class = "col-lg-2 control-label" })
        <div class="col-lg-10">
            @Html.EmailFor(m => m.Email, new { @class = "form-control", placeholder = "Email" })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Email)                                 
        </div>            
    </div>
```

And the html source gives:

```
<div class="form-group">            
    <label class="col-lg-2 control-label" for="Email">Email</label>
    <div class="col-lg-10">
        <input class="form-control" data-val="true" data-val-required="The Email field is required." id="Email" name="Email" placeholder="Email" type="email" value="" />
        <span class="field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-for="Email" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>                                 
    </div>            
</div>
```

Comment: FYI, you can in fact use html attributes with EditorFor, but you would have to write your own template for it.  Which is a lot less intrusive than writing a new Html helper.

Comment: I agree with u and i did see a few remarks about using templates. Sadly i'm only at the learning stage in MVC right now and didn't take the time to look at Editor and Display templates.

Comment: As of MVC 5.1 you can use HTML attributes with EditorFor tags.

Answer (score 9):

Love it when can drive this type of stuff off the model!!  I decorated my models with  `[DataType(DataType.PhoneNumber)]`, and all but one worked.

I realized the hard way that `@Html.TextBoxFor` doesn't render the `type="<HTML5 type>"` but `@Html.EditorFor` does.  Makes sense I guess now that I think about it, but posting this to maybe save others the frustrating few minutes that I just lost;)

Comment: In my case not working with TextBoxFor and EditorFor in both of IE and Chrome, What is the wrong you think?

Answer (score 2):

I found my self wanting the number spinner you get when using `<input type='number' />` from an HtmlHelper, and ended up solving it my self.

In a similar fashion to RPAlbert's Html.EmailFor answer above, I started off using the normal Html.TextBoxFor, but then I used LinqToXml to modify the HTML rather than just using a string replace.

The advantage of starting with the Html.TextBoxFor is that you can use of all the client side validation stuff that MVC does for you. In this case I am using the values from the `data-val-range` attributes to set the min/max attributes needed to constrain the spinner.

```
public static HtmlString SpinnerFor<TModel, TValue>(this HtmlHelper<TModel> html, Expression<Func<TModel, TValue>> expression, object htmlAttributes)
{
    XDocument _xml = XDocument.Parse(html.TextBoxFor(expression, htmlAttributes).ToString());
    XElement _element = _xml.Element("input");

    if (_element != null)
    {
        _element.SetAttributeValue("type", "number");

        if (_element.Attribute("data-val-range-max") != null) 
            _element.SetAttributeValue("max", _element.Attribute("data-val-range-max").Value);

        if (_element.Attribute("data-val-range-min") != null) 
            _element.SetAttributeValue("min", _element.Attribute("data-val-range-min").Value);
    }

    return new HtmlString(_xml.ToString());
}
```

You would then use it as you would any other HtmlHelper in your views:

`@Html.SpinnerFor(model => model.SomeNumber, new { htmlAttribute1 = "SomeValue" })`

This was my implementation of it anyway, from you question I can see that you wanted:

`@Html.NumericInputFor(model => model.Foo, min:0, max:100)`

It would be very simple to tweak my method to do this as follows:

```
public static HtmlString NumericInputFor<TModel, TValue>(this HtmlHelper<TModel> html, Expression<Func<TModel, TValue>> expression, int min, int max)
{
    XDocument _xml = XDocument.Parse(html.TextBoxFor(expression, htmlAttributes).ToString());
    XElement _element = _xml.Element("input");

    if (_element != null)
    {
        _element.SetAttributeValue("type", "number");
        _element.SetAttributeValue("min", min);
        _element.SetAttributeValue("max", max);
    }

    return new HtmlString(_xml.ToString());
}
```

Basically all I have done is to rename it and provide min/max as arguments rather than getting them from DataAnnotation attributes.

I hope that helps!